# QGIS crash when using args=0 with qgsfunction

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-custom-function

I am trying to define a custom function in QGIS 2.8.1 that takes no arguments.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args=0, group='Custom')
def test(value1, feature, parent):
    return 'test'
```

This results in a QGIS crash. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try removing value1 from the arg list

Comment: Tried removing value1 from the arg. It stops the crash, but in the expression editor using $test gives "Eval Error: test() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)"

Comment: hmm ok it should work. I will test it.

Comment: I copy and pasted your code. It works fine in my OSGEO QGIS 2.8.1. You will need the value1 argument for removing the argument error. I think the problem  is outside the function somewhere else in the py file of the function. What else do you have in the py file (folder ..qgis2\python or ..qgis2\python\expressions)? Can you try to move you code to a new clean py file in the ..qgis2\python folder and import the file in the startup.py

Comment: Thanks @Jakob. Clearing my .qgis2/python/expressions/ directory solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

AS @Jakob pointed out in the comments, clearing the .qgis2/python/expressions/ directory solved the problem.